# How do I access a remote Windows command line from a linux shell?

Tags: linux, openssh, windows-server

It looks like a there are a few options out there, but what's the simplest way to do it?
It looks like you can install OpenSSH on Windows, but I'd like to use existing utilities if possible.
I saw that Windows server has the new Windows Remote Shell. Is there some way to access that from a linux terminal?

Comment: just go with openssh, easier.

Comment: I would recommend `WinExe` - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinExe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PowerShell -> [run-powershell-through-ssh](http://hindenes.com/trondsworking/2012/05/17/run-powershell-through-ssh/)

Comment: Thanks. I like this method.

Comment: I also found installing freeSSHd + cygwin and setting c:\wygwin\bin\bash.exe to my shell in freeSSHd was useful.